# Base64 Encoded data submitted as form data

Tags: php

I am using fairly simple flash script that I put together to take a picture using a webcam which then calls a JavaScript function on the page that inserts that data into a hidden form element as a base64 encoded string. This is then submitted to a PHP script which converts the base64 string back to the image format and saves it to the server. I've had no problems with this working but the one thing I am kind of hoping to achieve is a method to give feedback to the user on the progress of the form post since with some webcams the image can be quite large. It may simply not be possible and I know off hand I wasn't able to find any specific details on achieving this. It's not the end of the world if I can't achieve it but I was hoping maybe there is a way and it's just something I'm not aware of. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need APC, and to tweak your upload form a little.

This tutorial makes it look pretty simple: http://www.haughin.com/2007/10/23/php-upload-progress-with-php-52-apc/

Full Disclosure: I haven't tried it, but it looks fairly straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for that info but I'm not seeing a way I could make it work for me because it's not actually posting a file, it's simply posting form inputs which contain the image data. It's actually inserting the image data into a hidden form element.